# Why can't I access List<T> through System.Collections.Generic?

Tags: c#, unity

I have the following small and incomplete script, and I was wondering if anyone knew about this issue. I'm trying to access `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`, but I keep getting the error `The name 'List' does not exist in the current context.`. I have the proper headers, but it still won't work. Here's my code for reference.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

/// <summary>
/// C# File for generating worlds with
/// LIMITED terrain.
/// </summary>
public class GenerateLimitedTerrain : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public int positiveWorldLength;
    public int negativeWorldLength;
    public int positiveWorldHeight;
    public int negativeWorldHeight;

    public GameObject grassBlock;
    public GameObject dirtBlock;
    public GameObject stoneBlock;

    private List blockData = new List<List<GameObject>>(); // The error occurs on this at line at 'List'
}
```

Comment: Don't you need List<List<GameObject>> after private too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:
`private List<List<GameObject>> blockData = new List<List<GameObject>>();`

It needs to know what kind of List the variable is.